# RecyclerView.Adapter not calling onCreateViewHolder or onBindViewHolder, onAttachedToRecyclerView is called

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have records fetch to the cursor used by the adapter and call notifyDataSetChanged() but neither onCreateViewHolder or onBindViewHolder are being called.  The adapter is being created (onAttachedToRecyclerView is being called), obviously the RecyclerView is showing no records.  Been looking at this for a couple of hours and no joy.

I have put the code below but here is the **logcat**, the whole project is as https://github.com/funkytwig/tasktimer.

```
DurationsReportXX    com.funkytwig.takstimer D  onCreate
DurationsReportXX    com.funkytwig.takstimer D  onCreate: Setup adapter
DurationsRVAdapterXX com.funkytwig.takstimer D  onAttachedToRecyclerView
DurationsRVAdapterXX com.funkytwig.takstimer D  onAttachedToRecyclerView done
DurationsReportXX    com.funkytwig.takstimer D  loadData
DurationsReportXX    com.funkytwig.takstimer D  order=Name
AppProviderXX        com.funkytwig.takstimer D  query for uri=content://com.funkytwig.tasktimer.provider/vwTaskDurations
SingletonHolder      com.funkytwig.takstimer D  getInstance
AppProviderXX        com.funkytwig.takstimer D  query: 726 rows returned
DurationsRVAdapterXX com.funkytwig.takstimer D  swapCursor
DurationsRVAdapterXX com.funkytwig.takstimer D  getItemCount: count=0
DurationsRVAdapterXX com.funkytwig.takstimer D  swapCursor newCursor.count=726, oldCursor.cont=null
DurationsRVAdapterXX com.funkytwig.takstimer D  swapCursor notify the observers about the new cursor
RecyclerView         com.funkytwig.takstimer E  No adapter attached; skipping layout
EGL_emulation        com.funkytwig.takstimer D  eglMakeCurrent: 0xe837ed40: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xe83c0760)
EGL_emulation        com.funkytwig.takstimer D  eglMakeCurrent: 0xe837ed40: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xe83c0760)
EGL_emulation        com.funkytwig.takstimer D  eglMakeCurrent: 0xe837ed40: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xe83c0760)
chatty               com.funkytwig.takstimer I  uid=10162(com.funkytwig.takstimer) RenderThread identical 1 line
EGL_emulation        com.funkytwig.takstimer D  eglMakeCurrent: 0xe837ed40: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xe83c0760)
MainActivityXX       com.funkytwig.takstimer D  onStop
EGL_emulation        com.funkytwig.takstimer D  eglMakeCurrent: 0xe837ed40: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xe83c0760)
```

Wondering if "No adapter attached; skipping layout" is relevant, odd as avapter is definitely being attached.  Wondering if I can turn on some debug in RecyclerView?

**DurationsRVAdapter**

```
package com.funkytwig.tasktimer

import android.content.Context
import android.database.Cursor
import android.text.format.DateFormat
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.funkytwig.tasktimer.databinding.TaskDurationItemsBinding
import java.util.Locale
import java.lang.IllegalStateException

private const val TAG = "DurationsRVAdapterXX"

class DurationsRVAdapter(context: Context, private var cursor: Cursor?) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<DurationsRVAdapter.DurationsViewHolder>() {

     inner class DurationsViewHolder(val bindings: TaskDurationItemsBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(bindings.root)

    private val dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateFormat(context)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): DurationsViewHolder {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateViewHolder")
        val view =
            TaskDurationItemsBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return DurationsViewHolder(view)

    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: DurationsViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val func = "onBindViewHolder"
        Log.d(TAG, "$func: position = $position")
        val cursor = cursor

        if (cursor != null && cursor.count != 0) {
            if (!cursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
                throw IllegalStateException("Couldn't move cursor to position $position")
            }
            val name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DurationsContract.Columns.NAME))
            val description =
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DurationsContract.Columns.DESCRIPTION))
            val startTime =
                cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(DurationsContract.Columns.START_TIME))
            val totalDuration =
                cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(DurationsContract.Columns.DURATION))
            val userDate =
                dateFormat.format(startTime * 1000)  // The database stores seconds, we need milliseconds
            val totalTime = formatDuration(totalDuration)

            holder.bindings.tdName.text = name
            holder.bindings.tdDescription?.text = description
            holder.bindings.tdStart.text = userDate
            holder.bindings.tdDuration.text = totalTime
        }
    }

    private fun formatDuration(duration: Long): String {
        // convert duration Long to hours:mins:secs String (can be > 24 hours so cant use dateFormat)
        val hours = duration / 3600
        val remainder = duration - hours * 3600
        val minutes = remainder / 60
        val seconds = remainder % 60
        return String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        val func = "getItemCount"
        val count = cursor?.count ?: 0
        Log.d(TAG, "$func: count=$count")
        return count
    }

    fun swapCursor(newCursor: Cursor?): Cursor? {
        val func = "swapCursor"
        Log.d(TAG, func)
        if (newCursor === cursor) return null

        val numItems = itemCount
        val oldCursor = cursor
        cursor = newCursor

        Log.d(TAG, "$func newCursor.count=${newCursor?.count}, oldCursor.cont=${oldCursor?.count}")

        if (newCursor != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "$func notify the observers about the new cursor")
            // notify the observers about the new cursor
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "$func Notify observer about lack of dataset")
            // Notify observer about lack of dataset, all of it from 0 to newItems,
            // i.e. whole range of records has gone
            notifyItemRangeChanged(0, numItems)
        }
        return oldCursor
    }

    override fun onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView: RecyclerView) {
        val func = "onAttachedToRecyclerView"
        Log.d(TAG, func)
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView)
        Log.d(TAG, "$func done")
    }
}
```

This is a RecyclerView used to show records for a report.  I am testing it with a Activity (Will put most code in a ViewModel when I have it working).

**DurationsReport.kt**

```
package com.funkytwig.tasktimer

import android.database.Cursor
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.funkytwig.tasktimer.databinding.ActivityDurationsReportBinding
import com.funkytwig.tasktimer.databinding.TaskDurationsBinding

private const val TAG = "DurationsReportXX"

enum class SortColumns { NAME, DESCRIPTION, START_DATE, DURATION }

class DurationsReport : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val reportAdapter by lazy { DurationsRVAdapter(this, null) }
    var databaseCursor: Cursor? = null
    var sortOrder = SortColumns.NAME
    private val selection = "${DurationsContract.Columns.START_TIME} BETWEEN ? AND ?"
    private var selectionArgs = arrayOf("0" , "1559347199")

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityDurationsReportBinding
    private lateinit var tdBinding: TaskDurationsBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val func = "onCreate"
        Log.d(TAG, func)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityDurationsReportBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        tdBinding = TaskDurationsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar)
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

        Log.d(TAG, "$func: Setup adapter")

        tdBinding.tdList.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        tdBinding.tdList.adapter = reportAdapter

        loadData()
    }

    private fun loadData() {
        val func = "loadData"
        Log.d(TAG, func)
        val order = when (sortOrder) {
            SortColumns.NAME -> DurationsContract.Columns.NAME
            SortColumns.DESCRIPTION -> DurationsContract.Columns.DESCRIPTION
            SortColumns.START_DATE -> DurationsContract.Columns.START_DATE
            SortColumns.DURATION -> DurationsContract.Columns.DURATION
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "order=$order")
      //  GlobalScope.launch {
            val cursor = application.contentResolver.query(
                DurationsContract.CONTENT_URI, null, selection, selectionArgs, order
            )
            databaseCursor = cursor
            reportAdapter.swapCursor(cursor)?.close()
     //   }
    }
}
```

The main layout for the activity is **activity_durations_report.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".DurationsReport">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.TasksTimer.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.TasksTimer.PopupOverlay" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/task_durations" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

which contains **task_durations.xml** (This has the headings for the report)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/td_name_heading"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:background="?attr/colorButtonNormal"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="@string/td_text_name"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/td_start_heading"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:background="?attr/colorButtonNormal"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="@string/td_text_date"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/td_name_heading"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/td_duration_heading"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/td_name_heading" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/td_duration_heading"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:background="?attr/colorButtonNormal"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="@string/td_text_duration"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/td_start_heading"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/td_start_heading" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/td_list"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/td_name_heading"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.142"
        tools:listitem="@layout/task_duration_items" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The RecyclerView adapter used task_durations_items.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/td_name_heading"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:background="?attr/colorButtonNormal"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="@string/td_text_name"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/td_start_heading"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:background="?attr/colorButtonNormal"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="@string/td_text_date"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/td_name_heading"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/td_duration_heading"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/td_name_heading" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/td_duration_heading"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:background="?attr/colorButtonNormal"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="@string/td_text_duration"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/td_start_heading"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/td_start_heading" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/td_list"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/td_name_heading"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.142"
        tools:listitem="@layout/task_duration_items" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Probably `cursor` didn't get the data

Comment: Acording to the log it got over 700 rows.

Comment: For some reason getItemCount returns 0 as per the log `getItemCount: count=0`. Also this log got reported before `swapCursor newCursor.count=726...` which is somehow weird

Comment: Yes, noticed that, but not sure why.  Any ideas?

Comment: PS committed where I am up to  https://github.com/funkytwig/tasktimer

Comment: I managed to compile and run it without any problems; but the type definitions look different `DurationsReport` & `DurationsRVAdapter` not a part of the repo; probably something not committed?

Comment: OK, note to self,  push after commit! Thanks a lot for taking the time to help me.  I have pushed the commit now.  Add a few tasks with the + button of ActionBar then chose Generate Test Data from ... menue.  Then tap the eye icon to run report.

Answer (score 0):

you mentioned that "Wondering if "No adapter attached; skipping layout" is relevant". Have you not attached the layout manager?

Please try the following code in Xml layout in recycler view

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvVisas"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_visa" />
```

If you have not attached any layout manager recycler view will not show any data.

Comment: OK, tried adding that to task_durations.xml but could not get it working.  That is the layout with the androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView widget in it.  Did not put the . at the end (errored if I did).  Does not make any diference.

Comment: I've updated the code. Please take a look if that's what you did.

Comment: OK, thanks for that but ime afraid it did not help. I added 'app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"' to the RecyclerView butI am fairly sure I had attached the Recyclerview (tdBinding.tdList.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this),     tdBinding.tdList.adapter = reportAdapter).  onAttachedToRecyclerView was being called.